# Can I return an array of different objects from a method in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Im creating my own "CMS" in asp.net, I get the page content from the database and then create custom image objects and html content. 
For example, I have one method called GetPageInformation(string pageName) and it returns a Dictionary of name value pairs, but I want it to return 3 image objects, and 1 string text (with html markup)... is that possible?

Or how can convert this database string value into objects?

```
(image path ; alt text ; link)
"~/img/home/homeimage.jpg;my alternate text;my href link"

field separator: ';' 
registry separator: '|'
```

Then I fill one object, just for example:

```
string[] images = myDBstring.Split('|');

PageImage.Path = images[0].Split(';')[0];
PageImage.AlternateText = images[0].Split(';')[1];
PageImage.LinkUrl = images[0].Split(';')[2];
//...

//PageImage derives from System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image
```

Sorry for my bad english... thanks!

Comment: You can avoid splitting the string three times: `string[] splitResult = images[0].Split(';'); PageImage.Path = splitResult[0]; PageImage.AlternateText = splitResult[1]; PageImage.LinkUrl = splitResult[2];`

Comment: @phoog yes, guess I'm just lazy xD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may always return array of objects `object[]` or dictionary, ie. `Dictionary<string, object>`. However, I guess it would be better to create classes that meet your needs - ie a class that contains string with html content and array of images.

Answer (score 0):

All classes in .Net inherit from [Object Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), you can return an array o list of objects

```
  object[]
```